# file_get_content for dynamic XML / API file URL

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to display results from a dynamic XML file with different variable.

I need it to take specific content from my current PHP page and display results related to it.

I have this:

```
<?php
$xml = str_replace("\n","&#10;", $xml);
$myListings = file_get_contents("http://api.domain.org/restaurants/nearby?key=abcdefghijklmnopq&state=TX&zip=<?php echo htmlentities($l->zip)?>&limit=2");
print_r("{$myListings}");
?>
```

The

```
<?php echo htmlentities($l->zip)?>
```

bit is meant to pull the zip code from the content on the current page. But it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove PHP tags from the string. Use concatenation: `"...&zip=" . htmlentities($l->zip) . "&limit=2"`. Or rather use `http_build_query`

Comment: Ah! Silly me. Thanks!